# Uploading multilabel images from Drive to Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, drive

I am trying to upload png images from Drive to Google Colab. **The number of images is 12,000** but the process takes more than **70 minutes** to upload from drive to Colab.

Is there a way to make the process faster?

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")
```

```py
import glob
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image

filelist = glob.glob('/somepath/*')
X_train = np.array([np.array((Image.open(fname))) for fname in filelist])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the files to colab and then use those files, if they are not large enough to store on the colabmachine